# Re-activating click event after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, jquery-events

I've made a web page that dynamically gets new data through Ajax whenever an user has clicked more then two times on a random link (href).
Every single click that is made I need to detect the id of the clicked button. This is done by this bit of code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".buttonsMainpage", function(event) {
        numberOfClicks += 1;
        idOfWebsite = event.target.id || this.event.srcElement;
```

Now the problem rises whenever I've did more then two clicks and my Ajax function refreshes my DIV's content. This is done by this function:

```
function haallinks() {
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: site_url + "/index/readWebsiteLinks",
        data: {id: $('#categorieId').val()},
        success: function(result) {
            $("#resultaat").html(result);
            $('#resultaat').bind('click');
        }
    });
}
```

Somehow every time my ajax gets the new data and puts it in my div (`#resultaat`) I cannot detect my ID's anymore.
Without further ado this is my FULL code, so you can see the whole picture:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var focusedOrNot = 2;
    var idOfWebsite;
    var bothEventsOrOne = 0;
    var numberOfClicks = 0;
    function haallinks() {
        $.ajax({type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: site_url + "/index/readWebsiteLinks",
            data: {id: $('#categorieId').val()},
            success: function(result) {
                $("#resultaat").html(result);
                $('#resultaat').bind('click');
            }
        });
    }

    function websiteTellerVerhogenInDb() {
        $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: site_url + "/index/websiteCount",
            data: {id: idOfWebsite}
        });
    }

    function styleSwitcher() {
        var cId = $('#categorieId').val();
        if (cId == 3)
            $("link[kleur=true]").attr("href", thema_url + "red.css");
        if (cId == 0)
            $("link[kleur=true]").attr("href", thema_url + "purple.css");
    }

    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#categorieId").change(function() {
            haallinks();
            styleSwitcher();
            $('#resultaat').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            showTextMessage();
        })
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".buttonsMainpage", function(event) {
        numberOfClicks += 1;
        idOfWebsite = event.target.id || this.event.srcElement;
        alert(idOfWebsite);
        websiteTellerVerhogenInDb();
        if (numberOfClicks >= 2)
        {
            haallinks();
            setTimeout(function() {
                userOnWebsiteOrNot();
            }, 2000);
            numberOfClicks = 0;
        }
    });

    function userOnWebsiteOrNot()
    {
        if (focusedOrNot === 0)
        {
            $('#resultaat').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            showTextMessage();
        }
        else
        {
            controlerenActiefOfNiet();
            window.setTimeout(function() {
            }, 3000)
        }
    }

    function controlerenActiefOfNiet()
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            userOnWebsiteOrNot();
        }, 2000);
    }

    window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.title = 'focused';
            focusedOrNot = 0;
        }, 300);
    });


    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.title = 'not focused';
            focusedOrNot = 1;
        }, 300);
    });

    function showTextMessage()
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (bothEventsOrOne == 0)
            {
                $('#tekstNewButtons').html('<h3>You have new buttons!<h3> ').fadeIn(3000).slideUp(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                bothEventsOrOne += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#tekstNewButtons').html('<h3>You have new buttons!<h3> ').slideDown(0).slideUp(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

The HTML/PHP part:

```
<div id="resultaat">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <?php
            for ($teller = 1; $teller < 21; $teller++) {
                $website = $websites[$teller];
                echo "<td><a class=\"buttonsMainpage\" href=\"$website->websitelink\" target='_blank' id=\"$website->id\"></a></td>";
                if ($teller % 5 == 0 && $teller > 0 && $teller < 20) {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Short version: Every time I click on a button in the div `#resultaat` I can get its ID because of the `id=\"$website->id\">`, but whenever my AJAX got new data for my div `#resultaat` the click event cannot detect those ID's anymore.
Does anybody have any clue on how to fix this or does anybody have an idea?

Comment: One thing, why don't you use the `dblclick` event? Triggers when you double click.

Comment: Because my buttons go of with a single click and I need it to monitor single clicks, so the dblclick event would be useless for me

Comment: Oh Okay. In your AJAX function you can't try removing: `$('#resultaat').bind('click');`

Comment: They do click and keep working as they should. My only problem is that  idOfWebsite = event.target.id || this.event.srcElement; cannot detect my id's anymore after my ajax call got new data and placed it into my div. It seems as if JavaScript cannot detect the new values behind it or something :s

Comment: Can't you just use: `$(this).attr('id')` ?

Comment: I've tried that too and sadly its exactly the same problem. All those methods cannot detect my ID's anymore. And it has to do with my Ajax

Comment: Did you inspect the element and make sure that your AJAX is actually adding an id?

Comment: @Shawn31313: Thank you so much for saying that. You gave me an idea to solve it. I in fact load a page inside a page with ajax, but BOTH pages look identical. But I forgot about the second page and I never added id="$website->id" there because I simply forgot about that.. Thanks for making me think about that ;)

ThomasLeu: The .On function is WAY better than the .live() function. I believe from version 1.7 in jquery .live() is also deprecated!

Comment: @ThomasLeu The live function has been deprecated ever since `1.7` and was removed in `1.9`. The `.on` function is the future `live` function.

Comment: @Yenthe Ha, your welcome. I suggest using `$("#resultaat").on("click", ".buttonsMainpage", function(event) {` for your on. As far as I can tell all your buttons will be in the element so no need to put everything directly on the whole document.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about live/on. Seems like I'm getting old.

Comment: @ThomasLeu: You might be getting old, but you're never too old to learn! ;)
Shawn: Will do, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$("body").on("click", ".buttonsMainpage", function(event) {
    numberOfClicks += 1;
    idOfWebsite = event.target.id || this.event.srcElement;
    console.log(idOfWebsite);
});
```

Also remove that `$('#resultaat').bind('click');` in ajax success because it doesn't do anything useful.

If you don't want to track `.buttonsMainpage` anywhere else on body, just be as specific as possible on the selector of the click event, as long as that element is not dynamic. It might even be `$("#resultaat").on("click", ...` if that link exist in `#resultaat` div only.